# how to access show{$id} path of resource controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller called userController and i named it 'user' in my

```
Route::resource('user','userController');
```

i want to access the `show()` method of this resource controlller.I have a page called ***show.blade.php*** inside my `resource/views/user/show.blade.php path`.The possible path to access the `show.blade.php` inside show() method is to write the following url in url bar:

```
mydomain/user/show/1
```

But when i type that url i get an error called:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

How i can solve this problem?

**my show.blade.php page is :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h1>This is show.blade.php</h1>
<span>{{$name}}</span>
</body>
</html>
```

**show() method of userController:**

```
public function show($user)
{
    //
    $info=userModel::where('id','=',$user)->get(array('name'));
    return View::make('user.show')->with('name',$info);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `URL` that you need to access to see the page `show.blade.php` is 
`mydomain/users/1`.

If you visit your `UserController` you can see the `show()` method.

So by default The resource routes produces methods like

`index`, `create`, `show`, `update`.

So in your case,

`mydomain/users` -> `index` method. 
`mydomain/users/1` -> `show` method.
`mydomain/users/1/edit` -> `edit` method. etc...

Comment: using {{$name }} , i am getting an output like an json object.How i can get the value out of it using ---- >  [{"name":"fdfdfdfdf"}]

Comment: Try `$info=userModel::where('id', $user)->pluck(name);`

Comment: it still has an array cloasing around it ,like ['fdfdfdfd']

Comment: You can also do something like: `$info=userModel::where('id', $user)->first();`  and pass it as `->with('user', $info);` and in your view, use `{{ $user->name }}

Comment: For the one you are using, try `$info=userModel::where('id', $user)->first()->pluck('name');`

Comment: Did you try this it?

Comment: if i use get() i had to access the value using {{ $user[0]->name }}

Comment: That is because you are getting an array when u use get(); . But first() returns just one raw.